# Issues with fluent-ffmpeg plugin in angular-cli project

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, npm, ffmpeg

I'have installed 'fluent-ffmpeg' plugin in my project and I'm including it in the following way in my component.ts file

```
declare var require;
var ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
```

I'm getting the following issues while building using ng serve

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './lib-cov/fluent-ffmpeg' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/ffprobe.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/recipes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/windows.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/isexe'
ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/mode.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/isexe'
ERROR in ./node_modules/isexe/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/isexe'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/utils.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'os' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/fluent-ffmpeg.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/processor.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/recipes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/capabilities.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/options/misc.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/options'
ERROR in ./node_modules/which/which.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/which'
ERROR in ./node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib/recipes.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'stream' in '/home/projects/angular/demo/node_modules/fluent-ffmpeg/lib'
ℹ ｢wdm｣: Failed to compile.
```

Can somebody help me in resolving this?

Comment: have you tried: `import * as ffmpeg from 'fluent-ffmpeg';`?

Comment: yes I tried that way. Still same issue

Comment: did you try to import the js file under the scripts array in angular.json?